# How to Count Skipped Items in PHP array

Tags: php

lets suppose that I have an Array;

```
$array = [1, 2, "Mohcin", "Mohammed", 3,];
```

I can Access this array and skip the items "Mohcin" and "Mohammed" inside the iteration using for or foreach loop and continue.. but my question how I can count the number of items that I skipped inside the loop? and that is "TWO" in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a line `$skipped++;` just before the continue ?

Comment: what is your skipping criteria? strings? names? things starting with capital M or Moh?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$array = [1, 2, "Mohcin", "Mohammed", 3,];
$skipped = 0;

foreach ($array as $element) {
    if ($someCondition) {
        // Remove the element
        $skipped++;
    }
}

// You access $skipped here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even without a foreach loop.

```
$array = [1, 2, "Mohcin", "Mohammed", 3,];
$skip = ["Mohcin", "Mohammed"];
$diff = array_diff($array, $skip);
$skipCount = count($array) - count($diff);

echo $skipCount; // prints 2
```

But if you want with foreach for the reason of more complex logic, do like this

```
$skipCount = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($value === "Mohcin" || $value === "Mohammed") {
        $skipCount++;
        continue;
    }
    // Do anything else when not skipped
}

echo $skipCount; // prints 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create variable that keeps count of skips every time you skip value.

```
$skips = 0;
for($counter = 0; $counter < count($array); $counter++) {
    if(skip) {
         $skips++;
         continue;
    }
}
```